# Whats the best way to decrypt push notification in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, encryption, push-notification, xamarin.ios, onesignal

Push notification messages that I receive in the app are encrypted, and I would like decrypt the message before displaying the content in the push notification banner. The app is build using Xamarin Forms and I am using onesignal for push notification.

I have created a Notification app extension, and I added the code the decrypt the message there, but the project does not compile.

```
public override void DidReceiveNotificationRequest(UNNotificationRequest request, Action<UNNotificationContent> contentHandler)
{
     ContentHandler = contentHandler;
     ReceivedRequest = request;
     BestAttemptContent = (UNMutableNotificationContent)request.Content.MutableCopy();
     var crypto = new CryptoNetCore();
     BestAttemptContent.Subtitle = crypto.DecryptText(BestAttemptContent.Subtitle,crypto.CryptographicKey);
     (OneSignal.Current as OneSignalImplementation).DidReceiveNotificationExtensionRequest(request, BestAttemptContent);
     ContentHandler(BestAttemptContent);
}
```

The error I receive is `Error MT2001: Could not link assemblies. Reason: Error while processing references of 'TestNotificationServiceExtension, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' (MT2001) (DrTalk.iOS)`

The crypto service is defined in a shared .net standard project , which I did reference in Notification Service Extension. What will be the best approach to access the crypto class from this method.

Please note that crypto key is not locally saved and its got from the server.

Comment: Can you please try the solution [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/137228/build-error-mt2001-could-not-link-assemblies-reason-error-while-processing-references), add  -v -v -v -v to "Additional mtouch arguments" in the project iOS Build settings will help diagnose the issue.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT : Adding -v -v -v -v to additional mtouch argurments does not give any detailed error report.

Comment: You can follow [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#mt2001-could-not-link-assemblies) to fire an issue.